# Relay: higher voltage allowed at lower current?

Tags: relay

Is it safe to use a 30VDC/1A relay for a voltage of 60V but a current of <100uA?
E.g. this one:
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/315/mech_eng_gq-1075992.pdf

Comment: REad the spec sheet .. section 2

Comment: Do you mean the max. switching voltage (110VDC) combined with the max. switching power (30W)?

Comment: yes 110Vdc max 30W max discharge and also 10uA min

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know that there has to be a min. current flowing through the relay. Why? I mean the applied coil voltage closes the relay. Why there must be a min. current?

Comment: Are you asking about the coil current or the load current? For the coil, there's two ways to look at it: 1. It's actually current that generates the magnetic field that closes the relay. 2. The coil has a fixed resistance. If you apply a given voltage, it's going to draw current according to ohm's law.  If you're asking about load current, there's a minimum current needed to make sure that oxides are cleaned off the contacts when they touch.

Comment: I'm asking about the load current and the information about cleaning the oxides off the contacts was the one I was searching for, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to use a 30VDC/1A relay for a voltage of 60V but a current of <100uA?

No, the ratings for voltage and current are separate, not related to the power consumed by the load connected to the relay.

The current rating is to limit the self-heating of the relay due to its own resistance.

The voltage rating is to be sure the relay can disconnect properly, without an excessive arc forming between the contacts and damaging them.

> Didn't know that there has to be a min. current flowing through the relay. Why?

The issue is [wetting current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetting_current).

A certain current is needed to ensure that oxides and other surface contaminants are burned off the contacts when they touch each other.