# Mechanical relay: higher current than rated current at lower voltage than switching voltage

Tags: power, current, relay

In general, is it advisable/safe to switch a mechanical relay with the following abstract conditions?

- load voltage << rated switching voltage
- load current > rated current

---

**Relevant Questions**

- [Relay: higher voltage allowed at lower current?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/295400/224767) states the following

> The current rating is to limit the self-heating of the relay due to its own resistance.

- [Understand Relay Specifications to Get the Most Out of Your Switching System](https://www.pickeringtest.com/en-us/kb/hardware-topics/relay-reliability/switching-and-relay-specifications)

> maximum current that the relay can sustain when being opened or closed and not sustain contact damage

---

**My Use Case**

I have a mechanical relay ([Digi-Key PN 281-6348-ND](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/1542460000/281-6348-ND/9843332/)) with the following specs:

- Switching Voltage: `250 Vac`
- Contact Current Rating: `10 A`

I would like to use it to PWM control a `12 Vdc` thermoelectric plate (Peltier module) rated to pull up to `15 A`.

Comment: Independent of any issues with the relay low speed PWM is a terrible way to control a Peltier module. The I2R losses will make it very inefficient.

Comment: So you already found out that if the current is too high, the relay might overheat or the contacts might be damaged (which will stop the relay from opening or closing) and your question is whether these problems are advisable and/or safe?

Comment: if you want to use the peltier to cool something PWM is a really bad choice, it maximises \$I^2R\$ heating in the module which you doe't want. it also puts more physical stress on the module accelerating wear-out.  Use a switching regulator instead.

Comment: @Jasen thank you for suggesting a better method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current rating determines the \$I^2R\$ losses of the closed contact hence, operating at 15 amps when the rating is 10 amps is going to result in early failure of the relay. The voltage rating determines characteristics of the contact when it opens. There is usually no trade off.

Answer (score 4):

Some switches and relays are rated for higher current at lower voltage, however **this** relay is specifically limited to 10A in the [datasheet](https://www.bpx.co.uk/file/Weidmuller-Relays-Catalogue.pdf), even at 24V.

[image]

If you exceed the maximum rating, especially by a factor as large as 50%, you can expect unpleasant things to happen.

Comment: Thank you @SpehroPefhany for finding a datasheet, and finding a DC usage spec!

Answer (score 3):

Your correct course is to use a larger relay with a higher current rating.  Simple as that.

The issue is thermal, and is caused by **current**.  The voltage doesn't really enter into it.  So using a lower than intended voltage doesn't help.

Voltage matters to the relay's ability to interrupt an arc.  At your low voltage, that's not the question; it's the contact heat when active.

Comment: Thank you for the simple explanation!